# How to efficently use mediaquery in flutter?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, stack, mpmediaquery

I'm developing flutter project, I'm using android studio emulator that size of 5.46 inches display. I use mediaquery for responsive design, but it doesn't work.

can someone help me, how to efficiently use mediaquery in flutter

Comment:  it was supped to be coma `,`, typo

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i see, btw I found `Flow` widget to be very handy for doing responsive, non linear layouts, check a full working example https://gist.github.com/pskink/10c8fd372113f0b36570db96d58d818e#file-flow_painter-dart-L156

Comment: the animation   is cool

Comment: @YeasinSheikh the devil is in the details: it does not use any `setState` nor `AnimatedWidget` or similar stuff: just `Flow` and `CustomPaint` combined in one widget

Comment: Actually, I'm still reading the snippet and trying to get my running some at a time .`super(repaint:` is responsible for updating ui.  I just need to motion-Blur on single item. I am thinking CustomPaint with mask might be enough. animation is like AnimatedPosition in motion, do you have any suggestion for this @pskink

Comment: @YeasinSheikh the nice motion-Blur effect is made in `paint(Canvas, Size)` of the delegate - comment out everything from that method and see the difference (lines 260-274)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh and here is a proof how easily you can make widget moving/sizing/rotating using `Flow` widget: https://gist.github.com/pskink/a8a497c11365e65dda48648ac07e302b#file-flow_resizer-dart-L550 - most of this code is redundant - for example you can remove two custom painters, they are just decorators - the heart of the code is very short custom `FlowDelegate`

Comment: Ok I will check after today's exam and how much i can get :)

Comment: Well I am able to run, so many things going on[cool specially second splash animation]. btw I was expecting user rotation after resizing option 

Comment: got it. btw are you are preparing this to create package or some sort of photo editor?  Another question is my vscode auto format break the flutter-coding style by little. Last one is it possible to take screenshot of ListView.builder(any widget that renders on demand) with RepaintBoundary .lots of question 

Comment: @YeasinSheikh ad 1) no, i was just playing with `Flow` widget and what it could be used for, now I see it is powerful, but little known thing. ad 2) are you using any custom code formatter? ad 3) yes, it can save any widget - btw recently in spare time i play with `RenderBox`es - check how "sizers" handles are rendered now :-), the magic is in `RenderWaterDrop` class - to my surprise it works even on chrome

Comment: 2) It is the default dart formatter on vscode.  (3),yea many things going on with math , btw a cool part is `countStream(ready>steady>go)`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh countStream is cool? forget it... check how sizers look now and how they move on selecting / deselecting top widget, this is cool now ;-)

Comment: V2 is amazing > magnification , btw ResizerFrameRenderObjectWidget cant be const on flutter 3.7.9 flutter

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i am on 3.9 and it warns me if it is not `const` - I intentionally made the sizers bigger in `flow_resizer.dart` to show that it is not "normal", perfect magnification but deformed one.. see https://pasteboard.co/D3FV5y45YOxU.jpg - even the arrow indicator is deformed where it is painted under the glass

Comment: well it working fine . maybe limiting arrow paint & scaling will looks better on small case

Comment: @YeasinSheikh check this: https://gist.github.com/pskink/10c8fd372113f0b36570db96d58d818e#file-flow_stack-dart-L224 - it's "better" stack implemented with `Flow` widget - everything with less then 30 lines of code: delegate class `_FlowStackDelegate`

Comment: Pretty cool, seeing count-down, I was ready to play the game.  1q, do you disable auto code-format, curious how to represent [Matrix4 like](https://gist.github.com/pskink/10c8fd372113f0b36570db96d58d818e#file-flow_painting_context_extension-dart-L64-L69) . Q2, your IDE name?

Comment: Legend, yea ig `updateRenderObject` from `CompositedTransformFollower` handling the update. render object is great.

Comment: got it.........✌

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class built upon [Layout Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) and [Media Query](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html), to help you to effectively use Media Query to make your designs responsive.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class ScreenBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, LayoutSize size) builder;
  const ScreenBuilder({
    Key? key,
    required this.builder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return builder(context, getSize(context));
  },
 );
   }

 LayoutSize getSize(BuildContext context) {
 final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
 bool isSmall = width <= 900.0;
 bool isSmaller = width <= 535.0;
 LayoutSize size = LayoutSize.large;
 if (isSmaller) {
  size = LayoutSize.min;
   } else if (isSmall) {
  size = LayoutSize.mid;
  }
  return size;
 }
}

enum LayoutSize { min, mid, large }
```